# Is it possible to change the management/commands directory in Django?

Tags: django

In Django it's possible to write [custom management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/). These are stored by default in the  `proj/app/management/commands` directory of your application.

**Is there a way to change this location to a custom directory?**

E.g. `/proj/cmd/`? For example, to change the `migrations` directory you can use the `MIGRATIONS_MODULES` setting. Is there an equivalent for management commands? It doesn't appear to be documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Django only looks for management commands in management/commands for your installed apps.

From [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1de9a92295af87846e810a40fbb9ceb6b8d3e773/django/core/management/__init__.py#L21)

```
def find_commands(management_dir):
    """
    Given a path to a management directory, return a list of all the command
    names that are available.
    """
    command_dir = os.path.join(management_dir, 'commands')
```

---

```
def get_commands():
    ...
    for app_config in reversed(list(apps.get_app_configs())):
        path = os.path.join(app_config.path, 'management')
        commands.update({name: app_config.name for name in find_commands(path)})
```

There is no variable set to change following folder location